# Как записать двумерный список List<T> в файл и считать его обратно с файла в List<T> наиболее оптимально в C#?

Tags: c#

Как записать двумерный список `List<T>` в файл и считать его обратно с файла в `List<T>` наиболее оптимально в C#?

```
internal class SpectrumPoints
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}

List<SpectrumPoints> points = new List<SpectrumPoints>();
```

Comment: Используйте сериализацию

Comment: Как я понял, ответ не подошел, удалил.